# Nexus 10 - Android 5.0.1 OTA upgrade, “no command” and suggested steps failed

Tags: samsung-nexus-10

I did rooting with Kingo root, and also i did factory reset. but i still can't use OTG
When I press power+voldown, boot menu starts and immediately shows "Downloading... Do not turn of target!" 
then i tried Hold Power + Volume Up + Volume Down, and then i can see recovery mode, but it still not working - no command ...
I still see "System update download" , still failed.
what can i try more?

Comment: you won't get the official updates on rooted Nexus devices

Comment: get custom rom like CyanogenMod or download ROM from Google site

Comment: What recovery? Stock, CWM,TWRP? It won't install like that. A factory reset won't remove root. You'll have to flash the stock images you can download from http://developer.google.com

Comment: Thanks for all your responses ^^ I will try custom rom or factory images and let you know again. Happy New Year!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on installing a custom rom you need to install a recovery to flash the the ROM. TWRP is good

To get Marshmallow on the Nexus 10 [Omnirom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-10/orig-development/rom-t3045066) is your best bet. You'll need to flash gapps and supersu for root too.

The nexus 10 received 5.1.1 [security updates](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#mantaray) until April 2016 that you can get OTA on a stock device or install manually, but manual installs will wipe the content of the device each time.

The [Unified Android Toolkit](https://skipsoft.net/skipsoft-unified-android-toolkit/) is good but the information is out there on the [Nexus 10 Cyanogenmod page](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_manta) on how to flash a custom ROM from the command line.